# stubbing a method for all instances of a class

Tags: javascript, node.js, sinon

Trying to stub a method `getSigningKey` of [jwksClient](https://github.com/auth0/node-jwks-rsa). However, it actually executes the non stub version of the function and returns an error instead of the `mockResponse`. How to stub it such that it will return the `mockResponse` instead?

```
const jwksClient = require('jwks-rsa');
sinon.stub(jwksClient(sinon.match.any), 'getSigningKey').callsArgWith(1, null, mockResponse)
const client = auth0authorizer.jwksClient({
     cache: true,
     cacheMaxEntries: 5, // Default value
     cacheMaxAge: ms('10h'), // Default value
     jwksUri: jwksUri
});
client.getSigningKey('abc',(err,key) => {
  // doesn't stub returns error
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code looks more complex than necessary, especially the Sinon part. I am assuming `auth0authorizer.jwksClient` is a typo in your example code, and that you really meant just `jwksClient`.

If you mean to stub the instance, you need to stub the generated instance, not a non-existing method on the factory method (which is what you are doing!).

That would simply mean

```
const client = jwksClient({
     cache: true,
     jwksUri: jwksUri
});
sinon.stub(client, 'getSigningKey').callsArgWith(1, null, mockResponse)
```

But if the problem is that you have no access to the generated client object for some reason, such as it being generated outside of your control, you will have to stub the prototype of the `jwksClient`. [It looks like](https://github.com/auth0/node-jwks-rsa/blob/master/src/index.js) you are not able to import the `JwksClient` class directly, as the lib is transpiled by Babel, and does not export the class. In that case, you can make use of `Object.getPrototypeOf()`.

Just invoke the `jwksClient` function first, and get hold of the dummy object returned. We will only use this to modify the prototype:

```
 const proto = Object.getPrototypeOf( jwksClient(options) );
 // create stub on the class method
 const stub = sinon.stub(proto, 'getSigningKey').callsArgWith(1, null, mockResponse);
 // proceed with test as normal
```

Just remember to restore the stub afterwards, as you might have weird errors in later tests otherwise :-)

Discloser: I am on the Sinon team.